# spring cloud config with native file

Tags: spring-cloud-config

when config files changed,the config server did not reload the changes. 
It can't monitor the native file changes or something wrong?

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          search-locations: classpath:/conf/, classpath:/conf/licensingservice/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwGF8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since that your configuration are packed in your jar if you change a configuration since that it is saved in your classpath the server do not see the modification. 
A better option is save these config in an other place outside the classpath.
you can use a configuration like below:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: file://${LOCAL_REPO}
```

in this way you can pilot the place with the environment variable LOCAL_REPO.
Of course I suggest you for the production to move the configuration repository to a git repository that it is a more suitable production ready choice.

I hope that this can help you